# Unify [sts], [spring-tool-suite] and maybe [spring-tools-4]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[Spring Tools/Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools) provides Spring tooling in IDEs, like [Eclipse](https://eclipseide.org/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

The tag [sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sts) is essentially used for [spring-tool-suite].

I propose to create a new tag, [spring-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-tools) (as the Spring Tool suite is called Spring Tools since Spring Tools 4) and synonymize both [sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sts) and [spring-tool-suite] into it.

While we are at it, we may also want to consider synonymizing [spring-tools-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-tools-4) to [spring-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-tools) as well, because I don't feel like it adds much value to questions and there are no (historic) tags for older versions of it either. However, if we plan to do that, we should also inform the Spring Team to maybe update the <kbd>Ask Questions on Stack Overflow</kbd> button on [The Spring Tools website](https://spring.io/tools).

Comment: I'm in complete favor of eradicating ambiguous acronym tags as much as possible; this sounds like it makes sense to (non-SME) me.

Answer (score 5):

**I suggest burninating [sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sts) instead of adding as synonym**

There are only so many combinations of three letters, so most end up used for a lot of different things. I think making it a synonym is likely to lead to more confusion than it solves.

In this case, "STS" could be the [AWS "Security Token Service"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html), and [there are 39 questions tagged both "sts" and "amazon-web-services"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sts+amazon-web-services) - that's nearly 20% of the questions in the tag. These should be **re-tagged with [aws-sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sts)**.

There is also an [sts-securitytokenservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sts-securitytokenservice) tag, which has questions about similar services outside of AWS. There may be some questions with the plain [sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sts) tag which should be using that one.

Since there are less than 200 questions with the [sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sts) tag, I suggest that if they were all manually re-tagged, it would be unlikely to be recreated.